# Microcontroller UART - acting bizzarely

Tags: avr, communication, uart

I'm using ATMEGA328P-PU and Pololu PGM03A (USB hardware programmer). I had a very simple code that was sending an 8-bit value back to my computer:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#define BAUD  9600

int main( void ) 
{
    // BAUD RATE (bits per second)
    UBRR0L = ( ( F_CPU / 8 / BAUD ) - 1 ); // 01100111

    // CONFIGURATION REGISTERS
    UCSR0B = 0b00001000; // enable transmitter (TXEN0)
    UCSR0C = 0b00000110; // set data frame size (8-bit)

    while( 1 )
    {
        UDR0 = 0b11110000;
        _delay_ms(20);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can read the data using the following command:

```
xxd -c 2 -b /dev/ttyACM2
```

Every now and then a very strange thing happens - without any changes in the code, suddenly I'm getting zeros:

```
00019d40: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d42: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d44: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d46: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d48: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d4a: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d4c: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d4e: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d50: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d52: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d54: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d56: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d58: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d5a: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d5c: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d5e: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d60: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d62: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d64: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d66: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d68: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d6a: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d6c: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d6e: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d70: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d72: 00000000 00000000  ..
00019d74: 00000000 00000000  ..
```

But there should be *1111000*. I noticed that:

- This happens after reboot
- Switching USB ports take no effect
- **Switching micro-controller produces the same problem. Even when I tried to write a simple code that simply blinks the light to a blank micro-controller, I can see the LED blink, but I still get 00000000's on serial port, but there should be no communication what so ever.**
- Normally the data is sent at fairly slow rate (when it's sending the proper data), but now the output is very fast (when it sends the 00000000's )

Any tips on what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: `UBRR0L = ...` doesn't look good; should be `UBRR0 = ...`.

Comment: You're not setting `UCSR0A`, specifically `U2X0`, so you're not using double-speed mode; hence, you need to divide UBRR by *16* instead of 8: `UBRR0 = ( ( F_CPU / (16 * BAUD )) - 1 );` As it is, you would be outputting at 19200bps which may confuse the receiver (framing errors...).

Comment: You can also do yourself a favor and replace things like `UCSR0C = 0b00000110` with more meaningful (and less error-prone) statements, like `UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ00);`.

Comment: "but I still get 00000000's on serial port, but there should be no communication what so ever" - You need to make sure that the µC's TX pin is *not* floating while it is connected to the serial adapter. Configure it as output or turn on the internal pull-up to avoid "random" output from that pin.

Comment: @JimmyB I changed UBRR0L to UBRR0 and changed 8 * BAUD to 16 * BAUD but the problem persists.

Comment: (No, I don't *really* think that `UCSZ01` looks "meaningful", but at least one can refer to the datasheet to see what the intention is :))

Comment: @JimmyB I noticed that if I divide F_CPU by 10, I'm starting to get 0b11111100.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the code, but the fact that serial port BAUD rate on my computer was different than on the controller. I solved the problem running the following command:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyACM2 9600 raw -echo
```